# split() Arrayindexoutofbound sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, split

i have this code :

```
     private void empcomboItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                          

    try{
    {
        String selectedItem = empcombo.getSelectedItem().toString();

        String sql ="Select matricule from employés where nom='"+selectedItem.split(" ")[0]+"' and prénom='"+selectedItem.split(" ")[1]+"'";

        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
        rs=ps.executeQuery();              
        if(rs.next()){
            jTextField1.setText(rs.getString("matricule"));

        } 
    }
}catch(Exception gh){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gh);
}
}
```

it keeps returning Arrayindexoutofbound  error, i don't know how to solve it

Comment: Try using .hasnext to check then .next to to retrieve data.

Comment: Also, I'm sure this is a duplicate, but my iPad only lets me give question id or url and I don't know it off hand. Search "using has() outofbounds and I wager you'll find many duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make sure that `selectedItem` has at least 2 elements in it which are separated by `space`. So first check it's length.

```
  String[] items = selectedItem.split(" ");
  if(items.length >= 2){
    String sql ="Select matricule from employés where nom='"+items[0]+"' and prénom='"+items[1]+"'";
    ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
    rs=ps.executeQuery();              
    if(rs.next()){
        jTextField1.setText(rs.getString("matricule"));
    } 
  }
```